# Merged Dictionaries in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I receive the problem "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key TextBlockForeground [Line: 20 Position: 37]" while the UWP app was starting.

ResourceDctionary.MergedDictionaries in App.xaml
[ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpYqL.png)

The resource with the key "TextBlockForeground" is placed in /Styles/ThemeStyles.xaml.
This error is related to/Styles/Controls/ComboBoxStyles.xaml, because this file doesn't contain the including of /Styles/ThemeStyles.xaml file, but the /Styles/Controls/NavigationViewStyles.xaml file also doesn't contain the including of /Styles/ThemeStyles.xaml file and I don't receive the same problem.

I tried to change the sort order of resource dictionaries, but it did nothing.

What are ways to solve this problem?
Including themeStyles.xaml file in comboboxStyles.xaml doesn't suit me.

Comment: Could you please share more details about the `TextBlockForeground` and how you use it in the `ComboBoxStyles`? I'm tiring to reproduce this behavior so I want to know how you implement it.

Comment: Of course, [link](https://prnt.sc/jrs09gK1rb5L) - the ThemeStyles.xaml contains the TextBlockForeground solid color brush. [link](https://prnt.sc/5kMjOD9bOCBA) - the ComboboxStyles.xaml contains the using of TextBlockForeground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Another way is to put the `ComboboxStyles` dictionary into the target page's resources dictionary. For example, you could still place the `TextBlockForeground` in the App.Xaml. But you need to put the `ComboboxStyles` dictionary into MainPage's resource dictionary if you need to use the style in MainPage.

**Old**

A quick and simple solution is that you could put the `TextBlockForeground` solidcolorbrush into the `ComboboxStyles`. Just put this one into the ComboBox style resource dictionary.
Like this:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't suit me, because I change the `TextBlockForeground` resource runtime. If I add in `ComboboxStyles ` this resource will not change at runtime. I try to understand, why `ComboBoxStyles` are loaded earlier than `ThemeStyles`. I know that the `MergedDictionaries` are loaded in the same order in which they are added in `App.xaml` file [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpYqL.png)

Comment: @Denys Another way is to put the `ComboboxStyles` dictionary into the target page's resources dictionary. For example, you could still place the `TextBlockForeground` in the App.Xaml. But you need to put the `ComboboxStyles` dictionary  into MainPage's 
resource dictionary if you need to use the style in MainPage.

Comment: @Denys Looks like the lookup order is for xaml controls but not suitable for MergedDictionaries. The MergedDictionaries is not looking for each other. I've created a `NavigationViewStyles` which you mentioned works, but on my side, it gives the same error like the `ComboboxStyles`. So you might need to make them into different level so the MergedDictionaries could find the resource successfully

Comment: Please, could you explain what does mean "different level", how can I do it?

Comment: @Denys Just like the second way I posted in my comment, put the `TextBlockForeground` in App's resource dictionary and then put the ComboboxStyles dictionary into MainPage's resource dictionary. Now they have are in different levels.

Comment: Thank you very much. The second way worked for me.